# Properly display html tr side by side using CSS

Tags: css

Good Day,

I am working on a table that will display data from MySQL using PHP which is pretty much working. My goal is to display this as a simple Identification Card using the data I have from MySQL.

I would consider myself a rookie when it comes to CSS and I need to understand why my display is not going as I wanted.

I did some research online and found this

http://jsfiddle.net/gajjuthechamp/cbEDJ/1/

It is working and I got the display that I wanted but for some reason the first column is shrinking. I tried changing the row width to 50% unfortunately it is doing the same thing. Kindly see image and my code below.

[image]

CSS Display Table Row Side by Side

```
 <style>        
    table {
        width: 100%;
    }

    table tr {
      display: inline
    }

    table tr:nth-child(odd) {
      position: relative;
    }

    table tr:nth-child(odd) td {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
    }

    table tr:nth-child(even) {
      display: block;
      width: 50%;
      margin-left: 50%;
    }
</style>
```

I also tried changing the values from top, left, margin-left, and width but first  still shrinks. Could no wrap also cause this issue? Any info or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Best advice: don't do that. A TR is a table *row* - they're not meant to be side-by-side. You're much better off using containers that are meant to be flexible like this (not tables, certainly not adjacent rows), rather than trying to break the way a table is supposed to be rendered.

Comment: I didn't  see any issue in your given fiddle.

Comment: @EdCottrell thanks for taking time to reply. If I understood you correctly what you meant about containers is using a div for each data row instead of using tables.

Comment: @ketan yes that is true. This is the jsfiddle that I found when I was doing my research.

Comment: Then i will recommand EdCottrell suggestion.

Comment: @ErphilCatama Yes. Don't try to force a table to be something it's not. Tables are for tabular data. If your data doesn't fit a tabular layout, use another layout. You might want to try something like Bootstrap (or, based on your example above, you may just need to use TDs instead of TRs in some places).

Comment: @EdCottrell thank you so much for the advised. Using tables was stuck in my mind and I am pretty much mislead. Moving forward I will note this down on my list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@EdCottrell

I finally got it working thanks a lot for the advised. I use div and it automatically work as I wanted it to be.

CSS for div

```
  <style>       
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }

    div#card:nth-child(odd) {
      width: 50%;
      background: lightblue;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    div#card:nth-child(even) {
      width: 50%;
      background: orange;
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
    }

    .parent {
      font-size: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .font {
      font-size: 16px;
    }
</style>
```

HTML for div

```
 <div id="card">
    <center><b>EMPLOYEE INFORMATION CARD</b></center>
    <br><b>Name: <?php echo $row ['EMPLOYEE_NAME']; ?></b>
    <br><b>Address:</b> <?php echo $row ['EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS']; ?>
    <br><b>Date of Birth:</b> <?php echo $row ['BIRTHDATE']; ?>
    <br><b>Polling Place:</b> <?php echo $row ['POLLING_PLACE']; ?>
    <br><b>Precint No:</b> <?php echo $row ['PRECINT_NUMBER']; ?>
    <br><b>Cluster No:</b> <?php echo $row ['CLUSTER_NUMBER']; ?>
</div>
```